# Schema.org and object hierarchy

Tags: schema.org

Actually I have a lack of understanding of how Schema.org objects are "composed" out of the given specification. Unfortunately I found no clear explanation so far.

Let’s take the JSON-LD example given at https://schema.org/SoldOut.
In "Example 1" we have given a property `offers` of type `Offer`. Within the only `Offer`, there is a `price` property specified ("13.00").

But if I look at the specification of object `Offer` given at https://schema.org/Offer there is no `price` property specified at all.

So my question is, where does it come from - the `price` property?
It seems that the `Offer` object merges the types `Offer` and `PriceSpecification`.
But why isn’t it then mentioned there in the `@type` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But if I look at the specification of object `Offer` given at https://schema.org/Offer there is no `price` property specified at all.

The `Offer` type *does* specify the `price` property.

The `price` property is listed on https://schema.org/Offer, and the `Offer` type is also listed under "Used on these types" on https://schema.org/price.

(Sometimes there’s [a bug](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/1584#issuecomment-322490085) where a type page doesn’t list all properties, so maybe that’s why you didn’t see it.)

---

A type always specifies the properties of itself and the properties of all its parent types. So for [`Offer`](https://schema.org/Offer), you can use the properties from `Offer`, from `Intangible`, and from `Thing`:

> `Thing` > `Intangible` > `Offer`

All available properties are listed in the first table on the type’s pages (unless the bug hits).

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of `price`-property could be coming:

The first kind is the kind shown in the example of `SoldOut`. The second kind i show you in the following example, based on the `SoldOut`too

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Event",
    "location": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "addressLocality": "Denver",
        "addressRegion": "CO",
        "postalCode": "80209",
        "streetAddress": "7 S. Broadway"
        },
        "name": "The Hi-Dive"
    },
    "name": "SOLD OUT! Typhoon with Radiation City",
    "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "availability": "http://schema.org/SoldOut",
        "price": {
            "@type": "PriceSpecification",
            "price": "13.00",
            "priceCurrency": "USD",
        },
        "url": "http://www.ticketfly.com/purchase/309433"
    },
    "startDate": "2013-09-14T21:30"
}
</script>
```

To say it in words, you could use `price` as stand-alone property, or as a part of the type `PriceSpecification` too. Both kinds of use are OK, the usage as a part of the type `PriceSpecification` is for cases, where you have to specify more properties as only the price and its currency, as listed under https://schema.org/PriceSpecification.