# Offers is not included as a property of thing on Schema.org

Tags: schema.org

I am reading up on Schema.org to be able to add the markup to a website I am working on. However, I'm already running into something I don't understand.

In the example for `Product`, it shows you should have a `div` whose `itemprop` is of type `offers`, but in the `Product` definition at http://schema.org/Product, I don't see `offers` as a property of `Product` at all.

If you look at http://schema.org/offers, it says `offers` is a property of `Thing`, but I don't see `offers` listed as a property of `Thing` at http://schema.org/Thing. What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Product`](https://schema.org/Product) does define the `offers` property. If you don’t see the `offers` property in the first table on that page (under the table heading "Properties from Product"), you are probably affected by [a (known) bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51021557/1591669). It typically works again when reloading the page later.

[`offers`](https://schema.org/offers) doesn’t have `Thing` as domain (but: `AggregateOffer`, `CreativeWork`, `Event`, `MenuItem`, `Product`, `Service`, `Trip`). If you are referring to the line "`Thing` > `Property` > `offers`", it doesn’t mean that the `offers` property is defined for/at `Thing`, it means that the `offers` property *is* a `Thing`. You can ignore that detail. What matters is the domain ("Used on these types") and the range ("Values expected to be one of these types") of a property.

Comment: You're right. I tested it from home on my phone and it worked. That's very strange. It still doesn't work on my office computer, though. I feel like that's definitely going to inhibit my proper usage of the Schema.

Answer (score 0):

It's perhaps worth highlighting the distinction between "types" and "properties". The vocabulary is a hierarchical taxonomy of the tangible and intangible things around us, which it calls types. In microdata, these use the `itemtype` attribute.

Properties describe the attributes of and relationships between the types, and in microdata use the `itemprop` attribute.

So, the type `Product` has the property `offers` (it's definitely there, you must be missing it<sup>1</sup>). A product can offer various things, one of which is the possibility of having some right to own or use it, which is described by the type `Offer`.

The property `offers` is indeed a property of `Thing`, but `Thing` is at the very top of the taxonomy, i.e. *everything* the ontology describes is a "thing", tangible or otherwise. So `Thing` is then broken down into more specific *types* of things:

```
Thing
- Intangible
-- Offer
-- Property
--- offers
```

So `offers` is a `Thing` like you and I are things — it's true, but we could be a lot more specific. In this case, `offers` is a property of the type `Property`, which in turn is a a more specific type of `Intangible`, which is a `Thing`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Image of "offers" property under /Product:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the explanation, but it's definitely not there. You can go to https://schema.org/Product and do a CTRL+F search for "offers." It is not on the page.

Comment: @steelstring94 I did while I was writing the explanation. Screenshot added.

Comment: Thanks. I can actually see it at home, but not at the office where I work. The only property there is "category."